# Filtering Content in Django using ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-ajax-selects

I'm working on a template that renders a list of product. 
I want the user to filter the content based on the properties of the product.

Those are my models : 
"""
Coutries, regions and cities tables
"""

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

"""
Categories and their subcategories tables
"""

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

"""
Product Table
"""

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Description = models.TextField()
```

"""
Products Location tables
"""

```
class ProductLocation(models.Model):
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

"""
Products Classification
"""

```
class ProductClassification(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        Subcategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the page i will have 3 inputs for location : 
 - Country, Region and City.
I think I should implement a Dependent/Chained Dropdown
I want to filter the products by country, region and city.

In another 2 inputs (Checkbox to select multiple choice) the user can select the category and subcategory to filter the products concerned.

How can I implement this ? 
I think That I will need Ajax and Json rendering. But I wasn't able to find a proper way to do it.

Comment: What code have you tried to use to implement the filtering?

Comment: I tried to implement chained fields using this library : 
https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects. I'm working it right now.